# In Celery+Python, how do I access to task parameters from the task_revoked function?

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

I'm trying to get to clean up some stuff after i kill a running task within celery. I'm currently hitting 2 problems:

1) Inside the task revoked function body, how can i get access to the parameters that the task function was called: so for example if the task is defined as:

```
@app.task()
def foo(bar, baz):
    pass
```

How will i get access to `bar` and `baz` inside the `task_revoked.connect` code?

2) I want to kill a task only when it's state is anything but X. That means inspecting the task on one hand, and setting the state on the other. Inspecting the state could be done I guess, but I'm having difficulty getting my head around the context inside the task function body.

If I define foo like this:

```
@app.task(bound=True)
def foo(self, bar, baz):
    pass
```

and call it from say.... Flask like `foo(bar, baz)`, then I'll get an error that the third parameter is expected, which means the decorator does not add any context automatically through the self parameter.

the app is simply defined as `celery.Celery()`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get tasks args from request object.

```
from celery.signals import task_revoked

@task_revoked.connect
def my_task_revoked_handler(sender=None, body=None, *args,  **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['request'].args)
```

This prints arguments given to the task.

**Update:**

You have to use `bind` not `bound`.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def foo(self, bar, baz):
```

Comment: The thing is the celery docs show some sort of class interaction, but give no more details other than that : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/tasks.html#context . If i try to just shove my functions in a class and call them , the self won't posess a state argument, which suggests that the decorator doesn't add anything extra

Comment: @omu_negru  Looks like there is a typo in your code, check updated answer.

Comment: that actually did it. Thanks a lot man, would not have caught that one